# Fabric Twitter kit timeline not loading

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, google-fabric, twitterkit

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebfqz.png) Is this got something to do with

"[Fabric] [Fabric +with] called multiple times. Only the first call is honored, please pass all kits you wish to initialize"

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. This usually means you're initializing different parts of Fabric in your app at different moments. If you can share your app's init code as it related to Fabric, then we can get you the corrected setup.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Got this resolved. In appdelegate.swift, I was adding multiple kits in different lines and just replaced those lines with Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self(), Twitter.self()])